# How can i set a new file name and directory?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a contextMenuStrip1 in the designer and two menus one to change the file name and one for the directory .

What i want is to make that when i click on change file name i will type inside the file name only the name of the file click ok and the name of the file to be created will be changed .

Second is the directory same thing i want when clicking on it it will change the directory name and location i selected.

In my Form1 i have this line :

```
ffmp.Start("test.avi", @"d:\", 25);
```

"test.avi" is the file name i want to be able to change .
And @"d:\" is the directory i want to be able to change .

So instead the file name and directory there will be some default variables with file name and directory already and somehow i will be able to change this variables throuh the application when it's running ,

Comment: So declare two variables (one for the file name and one for the directory), and change them in your application. Change the line of code you've posted to use those variables instead of the hard-coded values. What exactly are you asking us for help for? You seem to understand all but the part about changing your existing line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [OpenFileDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) to your form and use it to get a filename from the user.  You can extract the filename and folder using [Path.GetDirectoryName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) and [Path.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).  Store those values in variables at Form level and then use them in your `ffmp.Start()` call.

Comment: idel_Mind but isn't openfiledialog is for using when a file is already exist and i want to open/load it ? And if the file or directory are not exist yet and i want some dialog to set them ?

Comment: Sorry...I read it backwards...use a [SaveFileDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) then...